# Is it possible to have Gmail check before an email is sent out to a certain address, to see if that address is the one the sender really wants?

Tags: gmail

An administrator mistakenly sent out an email to the address group for everyone in the network instead of just to the person that they intended.  The email contained sensitive information and there was a lot of trouble over this.  I would like to know if there is a way to check (such as a text box with "Are you sure you want to send this?" or something like Mail Goggles, which I have seen but doesn't appear to work with Gmail now) before sending out an email to specific addresses, in order to avoid this happening again.

Comment: You could do some reading on Google apps script for Gmail, maybe you could write a script that does what you want.

Comment: From some short searching I haven't found any `onSent`-trigger for Gmail, so it might be hard to create a script like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way of running a script or such when sending an email, an alternative might be using "Undo Send" in Gmail Labs.

Go to settings:

[image: Gmail settings]

---

Go to the labs tab and enable "Undo Send":
[image: Labs, Undo Send]

---

When you have sent an email you will be given the option to undo it for a while.
[image: Undo]